# Why "IApplicationBuilder" couldn't find definition for "UseGraphQL"?

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am new to GraphQL. Whenever I am running my project it shows

> server is not reachable

I have crosschecked project files and I guess the issue is with the `Startup.cs` file. I am trying to use `app.UseGraphQL` in Configure function but the IDE could not suggest me a correct library for it.

This is my code:

```
using GraphQLMutationBasicCRUD.IService;
using GraphQLMutationBasicCRUD.Service;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using HotChocolate;
using GraphQLMutationBasicCRUD.GraphQL;
using HotChocolate.AspNetCore;
using HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Playground;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
namespace GraphQLMutationBasicCRUD
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IGroupService, GroupService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IStudentService, StudentService>();

            services.AddGraphQL(x=> SchemaBuilder.New()
                .AddServices(x)
                .AddType<GroupType>()
                .AddType<StudentType>()
                .AddQueryType<Query>()
                .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
                .Create()
                );
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UsePlayground(new PlaygroundOptions
                {
                    QueryPath = "/api",
                    Path = "/Playground"
                });
            }

            app.UseGraphQL("/ api");
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                 {
                     await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                 });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

For full code:
[GitHub](https://github.com/Anirudhrawat/GraphQLMutationBasicCRUD.git)

Comment: Can you share the project file code?

Comment: https://github.com/Anirudhrawat/GraphQLMutationBasicCRUD.git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you modify your code like this.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    endpoints.MapGraphQL();
});
```

I don't think you need `app.UseGraphQL("/api");`

You can browse your GraphQL client - `https://localhost:5001/graphql/`

Comment: Thank you so much @Anurag. I just have one more question. How should I understand the position of middleware of the new technology like here it is graphql?